# Test equality of collections without showing mismatches

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'm testing the equality of two files (images) using `BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS`.

The current code is:

```
ifstream ifs1(path1, ios_base::binary);
ifstream ifs2(path2, ios_base::binary);     
istream_iterator<char> b1(ifs1), e1;
istream_iterator<char> b2(ifs2), e2;

BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(b1, e1, b2, e2);
```

It works fine so far. The only problem is, that I don't want to show every mismatch. When the files are different, then there are thousends of differences, all binary values that aren't interesting. Basically I only want to know, if these files are identical or not. Can I somehow suppress the printing of the mismatch somehow?

Comment: Boost Says " This tool shows all mismatched elements in a collections."

Comment: Why not just use BOOST_CHECK with std::equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [log level](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/log_compil_time_configuration/log_ct_log_level.html) for test but there is no such [level](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/rt_param_reference/log_level.html), that will help you. I think the best variant will be to use `BOOST_CHECK` with `std::equal`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.